# Zero trick in JAGS for GLMM

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, jags

I'm trying to do zero trick but i got stuck. I tried the following model:

## model

dGC.model <- function(){
C <- 10000
for(i in 1:(2*m)){
    zeros[i] ~ dpois(zeros.mean[i])
    zeros.mean[i] <- -l[i]
    #log-likelihood 
              gamma[i] <- exp(inprod(X[i,],coef)+u[f[i]]+e[i])
              u[f[i]] ~ dnorm(0,tau.u)
              e[i]~ dnorm(0,tau.e)
    l[i] <- log(pgamma(alpha*gamma[i], alpha*Y[i],1)-
                        pgamma(alpha*gamma[i], alpha*Y[i]+alpha, 1))
    #log-link + linear predictor
    }

## priors

```
      for(t in 1:p){
        coef[t] ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
                   }# end of loop for t 
      log.u.Sig ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
      u.Sig <- exp(log.u.Sig)
      tau.u <- 1/pow(u.Sig,2)
      log.e.Sig ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
      e.Sig <- exp(log.e.Sig)
      tau.e <- 1/pow(e.Sig,2)
      alpha ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
```

}

ESTIMATION OF PARAMETERS by JAGS####

dat <- list(Y=Y, X=X, m=m, p=p, f=f)    # list of essential information for applying jags model

mod <- jags.fit(dat, c("coef", "u.Sig", "e.Sig","alpha"), dGC.model, n.iter = 1000)
but I got message from jags:
Attempt to redefine node u[1]

best regards.